# Why is shouldHideViewController called but not willHideViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitviewdelegate

I'm trying to implement a `UISplitViewController` which has different `UIDetailViewControllers`. I've created a delegate that all the detail views implement. It only has a `UIBarButtonItem` which is the button used to access the master view in portrait mode. All works well with one exception: when I replace the detail view controller, the button doesn't appear. In my master view controller, which is where I implement the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate`, the `shouldHideViewController` is called but the `willHideViewController` isn't. I checked that the `shouldHideViewController` returns YES. Any idea of what could make the `shouldHideViewController` being called but not the `willHideViewController`? Shouldn't they always be called together, if the first one returns YES? If I rotate the device after replacing the detail view, everything works fine.

Comment: Is the UISplitViewController the rootViewController of your UIWIndows? Have some trouble when it is not.

Comment: The master view controller has a navigation controller. When I'm on the third screen, that's where I replace the detail view. Is that a problem?

Comment: I finally got it working :-) I had to transfer the split view BarButtonItem to the new detail view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the delegate in awakeFromNib: or viewDidLoad: ?

If you set in viewDidLoad - your delegate won't be set when in storyboard

Comment: thank you thank you! NEVER usually need to use awake from nib, saved my bacon